# condition in Php after inverting is not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

there are two drop down menus as given below if i kept the "from" dropdown menu constant and only changes "To" the code in this format is working but when i changes value of upper drop down menu then it dosnt work and do not display database table which its connected and also do not give any error.as in code given below it works for" islamabad to lahore" but not for "lahore to islamabad"..

```
<p class="h2">Quick Search</p>
    <div class="sb2_opts">
     <p>
   </p>
<form method="post" action="haseeb.php">
 <p>Enter your source and destination.</p>
<p>
    From:</p>
<select name="from">
<option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
<option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
<option value="murree">Murree</option>
<option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
<p>
    To:</p>
   <select name="To">
<option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
<option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
<option value="murree">Murree</option>
<option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="search" /> 
</form>
</form> </table>

<?php


$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';

$database = 'homedb';

$from =  isset($_POST['from'])?$_POST['from']:'';
 $To = isset($_POST['To'])?$_POST['To']:'';




 if( $from =='Islamabad')
{
     if($To == 'Lahore')
   {


//$table = 'flights';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM flights");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
   }



$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<h1>Table: 'flights'</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
     }
}
 elseif ( $from =='Lahore')   
{
     if($To == 'Islamabad')
   {



if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM`lahore to isb`");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
   }



$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<h1>Table: `lahore to isb`</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
     }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is almost impossible to read and comprehend.

Regardless, the problem appears to be that your first if statement is `if( $from =='Islamabad')` which appears to encapsulate the entirety of the remaining php code, without any else statement, which means you won't see anything happen if that is not selected (it will appear to just 'not work'). Given your (lack of proper) indentation, this is hard to confirm without formatting it myself.

Please put a little more effort into your questions if you want better answers.